# Laravel 8 model factory using rand

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have just updated my Laravel installation from 7 to 8 and I am trying to convert my old factories to the new class based factories.

I have the following Laravel 7 factory;

```
$bottles = factory(Bottle::class, rand(1, 5))->create([
   'email' => $faker->safeEmail
])
```

How would I convert this to Laravel 8. The rand part doesnt seem to be working, I tried;

```
$bottles = Bottle::factory()->rand(1, 5)->create([
    'email' => $this->faker->safeEmail
]);
```

But i get the following error;

```
Call to undefined method Database\Factories\BottleFactory::rand()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [count](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models-using-factories)() method for the laravel8 factory:

```
   $bottles = Bottle::factory()->count(rand(1, 5))->create([
            'email' => $this->faker->safeEmail
        ]);
```

Comment: my mistake, thanks @Kamlesh Paul  I have fixed it